# Version 4.2.1 posts escaped characters

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I recently upgraded from 4.0.1 to 4.2.1 and noticed that when I publish to my page's wall, double quotes are showing up with backslashes before them.

e.g.

"Visit my site"

is now

\"Visit my site\"

This is happening in the post title, message, and description fields (possibly others as well, but these are the ones I've noticed). Has anybody else experienced this behavior or have a workaround? Or can anyone confirm that this has been fixed in version 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed in version 5 of the SDK. We are very close to a stable release of version 5 so you should be fine just upgrading to 5.0.6 beta.